# unbind remote service in onDestroy of activity on screen orientation change

Tags: android

In onCreate method of Activity, it binds to a remote service and makes use of AIDL intefaces. Is it required to unbind from the remote service when onDestroy is called on screen orientation change.?

If the activity un-bounded from the remote service in onDestroy and if no other contexts are bound to remote service, is remote service likely to get stopped losing the state that it maintains.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unbind all activities bound to a service, it will die immediately*. If you want to make sure it's up, you'll have to start it with `startService` and then bind to it.

*almost

Comment: Thanks, If startService is used to start the service, either it has to be stopped using stopService or stopSelf to bring down the remote service.?